# vue.js $watch array of objects

Tags: vue.js

```
mounted: function() {
  this.$watch('things', function(){console.log('a thing changed')}, true);
}
```

`things` is an array of objects `[{foo:1}, {foo:2}]`

`$watch` detects when an object is added or removed, but not when values on an object are changed. How can I do that?

Comment: I personally think the best answer is here: https://reactgo.com/vue-watch-array-of-objects/

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You should pass an object instead of boolean as `options`, so:

```
mounted: function () {
  this.$watch('things', function () {
    console.log('a thing changed')
  }, {deep:true})
}
```

Or you could set the watcher into the `vue` instance like this:

```
new Vue({
  ...
  watch: {
    things: {
      handler: function (val, oldVal) {
        console.log('a thing changed')
      },
      deep: true
    }
  },
  ...
})
```

[[demo]](http://jsfiddle.net/q3zd4fmv/)

Comment: Nice, this was a migration issue. In the last version of vue I used `true` as the last argument meant `deep`. Ty!

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

If someone needs to get an item that was changed inside the array, please, check it:

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/jonatan2m/h7sm7wbr/)

The post example code:

```js
new Vue({
  ...
  watch: {
    things: {
      handler: function (val, oldVal) {
        var vm = this;
        val.filter( function( p, idx ) {
            return Object.keys(p).some( function( prop ) {
                var diff = p[prop] !== vm.clonethings[idx][prop];
                if(diff) {
                    p.changed = true;                        
                }
            })
        });
      },
      deep: true
    }
  },
  ...
})
```

Comment: It seems a bit excessive to diff the entire array at every update. I wonder if there's a way to get Vue to directly tell me which element is updated...

Answer (score 9):

There is a more simple way to watch an Array's items without having deep-watch: using computed values

```
{
  el: "#app",
  data () {
    return {
      list: [{a: 0}],
      calls: 0,
      changes: 0,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    copy () { return this.list.slice() },
  },
  watch: {
    copy (a, b) {
      this.calls ++
      if (a.length !== b.length) return this.onChange()
      for (let i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] !== b[i]) return this.onChange()
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onChange () {
      console.log('change')
      this.changes ++
    },
    addItem () { this.list.push({a: 0}) },
    incrItem (i) { this.list[i].a ++ },
    removeItem(i) { this.list.splice(i, 1) }
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aurelienlt89/x2kca57e/15/

The idea is to build a computed value `copy` that has exactly what we want to check. Computed values are magic and only put watchers on the properties that were actually read (here, the items of `list` read in `list.slice()`). The checks in the `copy` watcher are actually almost useless (except weird corner cases maybe) because computed values are already extremely precise.

Answer (score 8):

You can watch each element in an array or dictionary for change independently with `$watch('arr.0', () => {})` or `$watch('dict.keyName', () => {})`

from https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch:

> Note: when mutating (rather than replacing) an Object or an Array, the
> old value will be the same as new value because they reference the
> same Object/Array. Vue doesn’t keep a copy of the pre-mutate value.

However, you can iterate the dict/array and $watch each item independently. ie. `$watch('foo.bar')` - this watches changes in the property 'bar' of the object 'foo'.

In this example, we watch all items in arr_of_numbers, also 'foo' properties of all items in arr_of_objects:

```
mounted() {
        this.arr_of_numbers.forEach( (index, val) => {
            this.$watch(['arr_of_numbers', index].join('.'), (newVal, oldVal) => {
                console.info("arr_of_numbers", newVal, oldVal);
            });
        });

        for (let index in this.arr_of_objects) {
            this.$watch(['arr_of_objects', index, 'foo'].join('.'), (newVal, oldVal) => {
                console.info("arr_of_objects", this.arr_of_objects[index], newVal, oldVal);
            });
        }

    },
    data() {
        return {
            arr_of_numbers: [0, 1, 2, 3],
            arr_of_objects: [{foo: 'foo'}, {foo:'bar'}]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to render and array and watch for changes on rendered items, you can do this:

1. Create new Component:

```js
const template = `<div hidden></div>`
export default {
    template,
    props: ['onChangeOf'],
    emits: ['do'],
    watch: {
        onChangeOf: {
            handler(changedItem) {
                console.log('works')
                this.$emit('do', changedItem)
            },
            deep: true
        }
    },
}
```

2. Register that component:

```js
Vue.component('watcher', watcher)
```

3. Use it inside of your foreach rendering:

```js
<tr v-for="food in $store.foods" :key="food.id">
    <watcher :onChangeOf="food" @do="(change) => food.name = 'It works!!!'"></watcher>
</tr>
```