# multiple watchers same function vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have several watchers that should be calling the same function, is there way to list them all in once statement?

```
watch: {
    'param.a' (nv) {
        this.calc();
    }
    ,'param.b' (nv) {
        this.calc();
    }
    ,'param.c' (nv) {
        this.calc();
    }
}
```

something along the lines of `'param.a,param.b,param.c' (nv) {...}` ?

**Edit**: I should have clarified, this isn't the actual code, but I can't use a computed property.

Comment: sum should be a `computed` that will be easy

Comment: sorry, i should've stated from the beginning, I can't get away with simply using a computed property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why you can't use a computed property but you could add the watcher in the `created` hook like in the demo below or this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/824uk46x/).

I think a watch for array is not implemented in vue. Also there is a similar question at [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283891/vue-js-watch-array-of-objects), just with Vue 1.x syntax. (There the watch is added in the mounted hook (previously ready) but I think you don't have to wait for DOM ready to add the watch. Anyway that would also work.)

My code is inspired by this [github issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/844). Only changed to a mixin and to ES6 arrow function.

```js
Vue.mixin({
  methods: {
    watchCollection(arr, cb) {
      arr.forEach((val) => this.$watch(val, cb))
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  /*watch: {
    'param.a' (nv) {
        this.calc();
    }
    ,'param.b' (nv) {
        this.calc();
    }
    ,'param.c' (nv) {
        this.calc();
    }
 },*/
  /* // not suported
   watch: {
    ['param.a', 'param.b', 'param.c'] : (nv) {
        this.calc();
    }
 },*/
  created() {
    this.watchCollection(
      ['param.a', 'param.b', 'param.c'],
      this.calc)
  },
  computed: {
    resultComputed() {
      return this.calc();
    }
  },
  methods: {
    calc() {
      let a = parseInt(this.param.a);
      let b = parseInt(this.param.b);
      let c = parseInt(this.param.c);
      this.result = a + b + c;
      return this.result;
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      param: {
        a: 0,
        b: 0,
        c: 0
      },
      // msg: 'hello',
      result: 0
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="param.a" />
  <input v-model="param.b" />
  <input v-model="param.c" />{{result}} {{resultComputed}}
  <!--{{msg}}-->
</div>
```